# How to manage sumproduct with not equal sign in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sumproduct

I wrote the following code. I'm Trying to use the sumproduct function in vba but it doesn't work.
When i run the code i get in the cell Q2 the error #Value!

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("Q2").Value = Application.Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--(T9:T10009<>N);I9:I10009;R9:R10009)")
```

If i edit the line to this i get the following error:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("Q2").Value = Application.Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--(T9:T10009<>"N");I9:I10009;R9:R10009)")
```

> compile error: expected: list separator or)

I also tried this:

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("Q2").Value = Application.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(T9:T10009<>"N");I9:I10009;R9:R10009)")
```

But same error as above ..

Comment: What's `N` in `<>N`?

Comment: The N is a String value that can appear in the column. So if the row contains a "N" value a certain Cell then he doesn't count that value.

Comment: Well it needs quotes around it then.

Comment: Yes i have tried that, but then i'm getting this error from visual basic : 
compile error: expected: list separator or)

Comment: I believe you also need to drop the beginning `=`. But please [edit] your question with what you're now trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`ActiveSheet.Range("Q2").Value = Application.Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--(T9:T10009<>" & """N""" & "),(I9:I10009),(R9:R10009))")`